# What is the meaning of installing a Perl module?

Tags: perl, module, installation

This question might sound simple, but I'm pretty sure that so many people do install modules without understanding what that means.

Could someone provide as complete of an answer to this question as possible? All technical details are asked for. What it means to install a module to a specific location. What local::lib actually does. What will happen if a module is installed but you delete the .pm file for example, and why. What values are written where. What environment variables are used. If you have multiple Perl installations, how is that separated. Anything that comes to your mind, I really want to know about that as profoundly as possible.

Comment: See Chapter 12, Intermediate Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit too broad to meaningfully answer. It depends on the module.

At a pretty basic level though - you retrieve some code, and you put it in a location where perl will find it when you `use Modulename;`. This might be pure perl, but it doesn't have to be.

`local::lib` supplement this process, giving you a mechanism for installing things when you don't have root access. (installing modules is potentially risky, because it's executable code for other system users).

CPAN is one of the key repositories, and has some more detail on the subject: http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Comment: ٍSo, the word "install" literally means "let Perl know where a module is". Nothing else. Nothing like registry entries in Windows, modification of environment variables, blah. Is that correct?

Comment: Perl has a set of paths where it looks for modules. You put your code in that path, and perl can find it. Usually there will be a degree of preprocessing of your module to make it 'fit' your system architecture, but not all modules will have this.